# Spring Boot Not Returning Data

Tags: java, spring-boot

The issue is the returning are not rendering in the webpage or in postman , for now it's returning `Whitelabel Error Page` , using `ResponseBody` resolves the issue but in tutorials and in documentations using the `ResponseBody` is not mentioned ! When reloading the page with the `/name` endpoint , it prints the `jo` which is in the `Test CLass` as many times i reload the page .Thanks in Advance.

Test Class :

```
package com.Learning.thols;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class Test {
    @GetMapping("/name")
    public static String name(){
        System.out.println("jo");
        return "tholkappiar";
    }
}
```

TholsApplication CLass :

```
package com.Learning.thols;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TholsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello da");
        SpringApplication.run(TholsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The Reason and a Solution for this issue or Misunderstanding.

Comment: That works as intended. Try adding `@RestController` to your class and remove the `static` keyword from `name()`.

Comment: Your controller methods cannot be static (and using ResponseBody won't fix that). They must be instance methods.

Comment: Thanks , jst learning spring boot and found the diff between RestConroller and Controller !